# Python read-file module

Tags: python, cmd

I have a .zip folder in my current directory. How can I tell python to read the "contents" file in the .zip folder? The contents file has the names of all files in the zip archive.

I basically want Python to read the contents file, look for a specific item, such as the word " program logo" and record to memory the corresponding value for "program logo".

For example, python should query the contents file and stop until it reaches the words "program logo". I have assigned a value, such as 123-123-23 for program logo. How can I tell python to record that value to a variable?  Should I use the read file module in python?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. What is the "read file" module? Where have you assigned a value for "program logo"? In the "contents" file? Do you mean it's data in a file in the zip file? Please edit it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Zip files are not folders, they are archives. They are files, and you have to open them for reading, like any other files.

I reckon you should look up the `zipfile` module. If you actually have a file called "contents" in your zip, then

```
with ZipFile('myzipfile.zip', 'r') as z:
   f=z.open("contents",'r')
   for line in f.readlines():
     if line.startswith("program logo"):
        # do something with line...
```

I'm not sure this is what you want, but it shows you how to look inside a .zip archive.

PS what OS are you using and what made you think that the ".zip" is a folder? How are you seeing this "contents" file? How did you create the "contents" file - is it a text file? and in particular, what does the relevant line (containing "program logo") look like? Without this information we can't answer the question!

Comment: I'm on windows.  The file in the zip is called Manifest.plist.  It holds the names and numerical key values of each file in the zip.  What I want to do is have python scan that manifest.plist for this part of the plist:<key>SupportedProductTypes</key>
 
  <string>iPhone3,1</string>
and have python tell me that based on the info in this plist, under the supportedproducttypes key, this device is an iPhone 4.

Comment: OK, then just use `f=z.open('Manifest.plist','r')`, and `if '<key>SupportedProductTypes</key>' in line:`. To extract the number, you chould use something like this: `m=re.search(r'<key>SupportedProductTypes</key>\s*<string>([^<]*)',line)` then `if m: return float(m[0])`. But ideally, as this is XML, you should be using an XML library like `xmllib`.